# Grails: How do I export a grails list to Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, grails, groovy, export, export-to-excel

I have a list with information and I want to export it to Excel.
How do I do it?

Is the "Export Plugin" any good? I think I saw one a while ago to export files to Excel but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: What kind of objects does your list contain? That might help to provide more specific answers.

Answer (score 6):

If you want *actual* Excel documents (rather than just CSV files), I've used the [JExcel library](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) with some success. Here's a quickly-written example that could probably be Groovy-fied a little bit.

*Edit: Updated my example to do this in a controller. Architecturally it would make more sense to split this up a bit, but this is just for example's sake.*

```
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*

class SomeController {

    def report = {
        def file = createReport(MyDomain.list())

        response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment;filename=Report.xls')
        response.setHeader('Content-length', "${file.size()}")

        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(response.outputStream)

        try {
            out.write(file.bytes)

        } finally {
            out.close()
            return false
        }
    }

    private File createReport(def list) {
        WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings()
        workbookSettings.locale = Locale.default

        def file = File.createTempFile('myExcelDocument', '.xls')
        file.deleteOnExit()

        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, workbookSettings)

        WritableFont font = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 12)
        WritableCellFormat format = new WritableCellFormat(font)

        def row = 0
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet('MySheet', 0)

        list.each {
            // if list contains objects with 'foo' and 'bar' properties, this will
            // output one row per list item, with column A containing foo and column
            // B containing bar
            sheet.addCell(new Label(0, row, it.foo, format))
            sheet.addCell(new Label(1, row++, it.bar, format))
        }
    }
}
```

Using this library lets you do things like formatting, using multiple worksheets, etc.

Comment: Ok, but I have an Icon, to export everything I have on the list to Excel.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following you. What do you mean when you refer to 'icon'?

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you're saying. Do you want this to be present via a button on every scaffolded list view?

Comment: It contains just regular data.

Comment: Ok, so I have a search section on top, like a header, and in it there is a button designed for exporting the search results into an Excel file.

Comment: Well, you'd have the button go to a controller action that (probably calls a service that) generates the file. The controller would then provide the file to the response's output stream so that the user could download it.

Comment: Yes, you could cram it all into a controller action, I suppose. I won't go into a big discussion on architecture, but it might be better in a service or elsewhere.

Comment: What do you mean in a service??

Comment: Grails has Services (http://www.grails.org/Services), which are for business logic. I've updated my example to just do this in a controller, but reading up on the Grails' link above might help give you a better understanding.

Comment: So, all I need is to update my controller to something similar to the code you provided??

Comment: Sorry, I had to finish some other things before exporting to Excel. I am getting an error on this line `WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings()`  it says : density.DensityController: 128: unable to resolve class WorkbookSettings  @ line 128, column 26.
           WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings()

Comment: Make sure 1) your controller has the imports from my example, and 2) the jxl jar is on the classpath. Where'd you put the jar file?

Comment: What jar file?? Maybe I'm having problems with the controller and domain names. The domain is density, and the controller is DensityController

Comment: In the first sentence of my answer there's a link to the JExcel home page. Go to that page and click the "Files" link at the top. Here's a shortcut: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/files/jexcelapi/2.6.12/jexcelapi_2_6_12.tar.gz/download ... you need to put the jar file in that zip in your lib directory.

Answer (score 1):

The [Grails Export Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/export) is excellent at what it does: export a list of domain objects (or query results) onto a single sheet (or page), in a number of formats -- including Excel. The ability to name columns, indicate width, transform your data on-the-fly is great -- I've used it in several projects.

```
if( params.format && params.format != "html"){
    response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Docs_${new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')}.${params.extension}")

    List fields = ["documentNo", "modifiedBy", "modifiedDate"]
    Map labels = ["documentNo": 'Document No', "modifiedBy":'Modified by', "modifiedDate":'Last modified']

    def fullDocId = { domain, value ->
        return domain.fullDocId()
    }
    def formatDate = { domain, value ->
        return value.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm')
    }

    Map formatters = [documentNo:fullDocId, modifiedDate:formatDate]
    Map parameters = [title: "${query}", "column.widths": [20, 15, 15]]

    exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream, Document.list(), fields, labels, formatters, parameters)
}
```

However, I've also used JExcel as suggested by Rob, when I wanted something other than a simple list. The right tool for the job, and all that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the JXL plugin for Grails for a while and it works perfectly.

It even has an option to write the Excel file to the response, so that the user can directly download the file using my REST service.

The link is: http://grails.org/plugin/jxl

Here is an example of how simple it is to create workbooks:

```
new ExcelBuilder().workbook('/path/to/test.xls') {
    sheet('SheetName') {
        cell(0,0,'DEF')
    }
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://github.com/sjurgemeyer/grails-jxl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial).